# More idiomatic ruby way to write @var = obj['blah'] unless obj['blah'].nil?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I'm sure there is a more idiomatic ruby way to write the code below:

```
@var = obj['blah'] unless obj['blah'].nil?
```

I've got a whole load of these to do (see below), and there must be a nicer way!

```
@num_x = obj['num_x'] unless obj['num_x'].nil?
@num_y = obj['num_y'] unless obj['num_y'].nil?
@num_iterations = obj['num_iterations'] unless obj['num_iterations'].nil?
@pe = obj['pe'] unless obj['pe'].nil?
```

I have a feeling that the `||=` operator may be useful, but can't seem to quite work out how to use it.

Comment: `||=` is for checking if the variable itself is nil. What are you trying to accomplish? Why is it a problem if these ivars are nil?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your circumstances, and unless the instance variables already have an existing value that you want to preserve if the value in `obj` is `nil` then it might not be a problem to just let them be set to `nil`.

Alternatively, you could write a little helper function like:

```
def set_instance_variables_for_non_nil_values(h, *keys)
  keys.each do |key|
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", h[key] unless h[key].nil?
  end
end
```

Then in your example code you would use it like this:

```
set_instance_variables_for_non_nil_values obj, 'num_x', 'num_y',
  'num_iterations', 'pe'
```

Comment: This is a good solution that does what the question asked.  However, I would say that mass setting of instance variables like this is a bad idea unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 2):

the shortest I can think of for this common need is

```
@var = obj['blah'] or @var
```

though if `obj['blah']` can be `false`, you'll need to go with your original version.

The `||=` operator tests the left-hand side, not the right-hand side, so doesn't apply here.

Comment: Your code it slightly different: In your example `@var` is not updated is `obj['blah'] = false`. In the OPs example it always updated except the value is `nil`.

Comment: @Veger: of course. that's why I mention that if `obj['blah']` can be false you need the original version.

Comment: ah sorry, I did not notice it! Oh you changed the answer... :) Now you are always updating `@var` I do not know whether it is very efficient, but it is shorted code-wise...

Comment: @Veger: I changed other things, but that part was there from the beginning (and the condition still applies) :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
obj['blah'] && var = obj['blah']
```

Answer (score 0):

if @var already has a value which is not nil or false then you can use

```
@var &&= obj['blah']
```

but I would be tempted to find a simpler solution maybe merging hashes
if there are lots of values.

such as:

```
obj = {:num_x => 23, :num_y => 75, :pe => 99}

locals = {:num_x => 1, :num_y => 2, :num_iterations => 3, :pe => 4}

puts locals.inspect #=> {:num_y=>2, :pe=>4, :num_iterations=>3, :num_x=>1}

locals.merge! obj

puts locals.inspect #=> {:num_y=>75, :pe=>99, :num_iterations=>3, :num_x=>23}
```

Which is used for setting options in many gems I have seen.